# Get values from arraylist java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following class

```
   public class Patient implements Serializable {

  private int id;

  private String name;

  private String desc;
    public Patient(int id, String name, String desc) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc=desc;
    }
```

And then the following getter and setter methods in this class.

Declaring the arraylist

```
  ArrayList<Patient> list = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

Adding run time data in the list

```
   list.add(new Patient(id++, name.getText(), disDesc.getText())
```

Now i want the read the elements stored in the list
How can i do that?

```
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

I use this but it returns the object address of the class

Comment: Most IDE's such as Eclipse and IntelliJ will be able to automatically generate a toString override for your class. I'd use those, at least as a template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to override the `toString()` method of `Patient`. There, you will return all information on the `Patient` object that you want to display.

**Example:** (my personal favorite)

```
 private static final String SEPARATOR = ", ";

 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

      builder.append("ID: ").append(id).append(SEPARATOR);
      builder.append("Name: ").append(name).append(SEPARATOR);
      builder.append("Desc: ").append(desc);

      return builder.toString();
 }
```

**Example 2:**

```
 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
      return "ID: " + id + ", Name: " + name + ", Desc: " + desc;
 }
```

**Example 3:**

```
 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
      return MessageFormat.format("ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Desc: {2}", id, name, desc);
 }
```

Use either one. It is a matter of preference.

Comment: Why not just use: `return "ID: " + id + " | Name: " + name + " | Desc: " + desc;`? Simpler to read IMO, and just as efficient. Alternatively, use `String.format`.

Comment: @JonSkeet From my knowledge, `StringBuilder` is more efficient than concatenating strings. Am I wrong? I've developed a habit for using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: loved your personal favorite

Comment: I believe is everything is on a single command then java is clever and uses string buolder behind the scenes anyway

Comment: @RichardTingle That's actually a really good idea for a SO question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the element,

```
((Patient) list.get(0)).getName();
```

And you must add a public getter method to your `Patient` class.